# How to customize style of qt-creator IDE

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Just started using qt-creator IDE, while really enjoying it, I need 2 to customize main toolbar and statusbar to make it look better on a 4k monitor. I read, and with some success, used -stylesheet option with custom css to do so, but could not find a way to make main toolbar with it's buttons (this toolbar is right under main menu) and status toolbar bigger. Here is the picture to explain my problem here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to set in the Stylesheet (.qss) the iconSize for all QToolBar items.

```
QToolBar
{
   qproperty-iconSize: 64px;
}
```

If this is not reacting, try to use the Asterisk for all Elements in the ToolBar.

```
QToolBar *
{
   qproperty-iconSize: 64px;
}
```

An Example of my QToolBar Style.

```
.MainWindow QToolBar
{
    qproperty-movable: true; /* set false, to be fixed in position */
    qproperty-iconSize: 64px;
    spacing: 8px;
    subcontrol-origin: content;
    subcontrol-position: center middle;
    border: 1px solid red;

    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

In the MainWindow there is only on Toolbar.

You have to guess what the ToolBar is Named, if at all.
If You also set the FontSize for the QStatusBar it could resize.
The following is specific to the App I style.

See the Instance Selector with the Hashtag. With that I resize All Fonts to one Size, also All Child Elements of it.
On a 43inch FullHD and a distance of 2-3 meters, I like to set the Fontsize to 22pt.

```
#MainWindowServerTabsWidget *,
QStatusBar *,
QMenu,
QMenu::tearoff,
QMenuBar,
MainWindow QToolTip
{
    font-size: 16pt;
}

QDialogButtonBox
{
        dialogbuttonbox-buttons-have-icons: false;
}

QDialog *, ImprovedWidget * /* enlarge all backbone fonts and icons */
{
    font-size: 12pt;
    qproperty-iconSize: 48px;
}

#ContentsWidget, #profileManager /* resize the width in options window for   the left index and the profile index */
{
    min-width: 180px;
}
```

This is guesswork, if You don't have access to the Classname.

If You got luck could You provide Your Values for Fontsize and Iconsize, for us who have only 14inch screens up to FullHD.

Oops Forgot about the StatusBar.

Try This.

```
QStatusBar QLabel
{
   font-size: 12pt;
}
```

Or
     QStatusBar *
     {
       font-size: 12pt;
     }

Or the not so good Idea, but...

```
QStatusBar
{
  min-height: 40px;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
```

Comment: You didn't mention the location of the this `.qss` file or **how** to use it.

Comment: @qed Hi. You are right, but this is out of my expirience, I never used the IDE (QT-IDE), so I dont know how the File is named or in which folder to find the file. Maybe someone can help with the Filelocation for the "IDE Restyling". The Howto is not easy to explain inside this "Textbox". But it is like a CSS-File (V 1.3 ?). So just a QSS instead of CSS. But some of the "Internal" Selectors, are not obvious like in CSS. Helpfull are the Searchengine(s) they have Alot of Examples. "QStatusBar *" Is the Selector for all inside the StatusBar. Excuse me, but I used the QSS editing for TeamSpeak.